# Does Oracle AQ support exclusive consumers?

Tags: oracle, jms, activemq-classic

I've been looking everywhere for this. Does Oracle AQ support something equivalent to ActiveMQs [Exclusive consumers](http://activemq.apache.org/exclusive-consumer.html)?

What other strategies could potentially solve the same problem in Oracle AQ if it doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If OracleAQ does not support exclusive consumer functionality (I'm pretty sure it doesn't), you need to push the coordination of exclusivity to the application tier. This is a real pain, and difficult to implement.

Alternatively, set up an ActiveMQ broker with a Camel route that consumes from AQ and feeds the messages onto a corresponding ActiveMQ queue, which then uses exclusive consumers.